# Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <main>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

I'm working in a project that uses:

- react/react-dom@16.9.0
- @loadable/component
- styled-components
- react-router-dom

The application renders both **server** side and **client** side.

I'm using `@loadable/component` to dynamically code split this way.

router.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const NotFound = loadable(() =>
  import('../components/NotFound/NotFound' /* webpackChunkName: "notfound" */)
)

const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
)

export default routes
```

When loading the page, this error appear on the console and the page seems to flick for a second.

```
react-dom.development.js:546 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <main>.
```

When I check the output in both sides (server/client), they are **identical**.

When I remove `@loadable/component` like bellow, it works and the error is gone.

router-without-loadable.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound/NotFound'

const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
)

export default routes
```

Seems to be something to do with `@loadable/component` but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: `@loadable` is used for SSR meaning your pages are compiled at server side and sent as HTML to client side

Comment: Yes, well the HTML is not send to the client, is sent to the browser as a response. But yeah my problem is along the lines of dynamic imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally have an answer for this:

1. For `@loadable/component` to work properly, you need to put the magic webpack comment (`/* webpackChunkName: "notfound" */`) before the path of the file this way.

```
const NotFound = loadable(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "notfound" */ '../components/NotFound/NotFound')
)
```

Reference:

https://github.com/smooth-code/loadable-components/issues/23

2. And more important, in the server side, you need to wrap you app in a `ChunkExtractorManager` and pass the client extractor (I was passing the server extractor, it's not very clear in the docs).

```
const statsFile = path.resolve('./wwwroot/dist/loadable-stats.json')
const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({ 
  statsFile, 
  entrypoints: ['client'] // name of the proper webpack endpoint (default: main)
})

<ChunkExtractorManager extractor={extractor}>
  <App />
</ChunkExtractorManager>
```

Here is a proper clear example on how to implement it:

https://github.com/iamssen/seed

**Update 24.09.2019**

Added to the official docs

https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/loadable-components/docs/server-side-rendering/#chunkextractor-entrypoints

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `NotFound` component is not loaded and thus `Route` dont know what to render which is causing the error.

You would need to modify something like below:

```
<Route path="/404/" exact component={props => <NotFound {...props} />} />
```

Comment: The `NotFound` component is rendered perfectly in the server and in the client, as I said, the outputs are identical. That is why I'm wondering why when I add dynamic import doesn't work and when I remove them it does work. It's nothing to do with the router otherwise it wont work with or without dynamic imports, if it makes sense.